# Making wordlists with different word lengths?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, for-loop

I want to create wordlists with different word length. my src for...

length=1:

```
for(int a=97;a<=122;a++)
   String foo=String.valueOf((char)a);
```

length=2:

```
for(int a=97;a<=122;a++)
    for(int b=97;b<=122;b++) 
       String foo=String.valueOf((char)a+""+(char)b);
```

Any ideas how to improve this code so it is independent of the actual string length?

Comment: This looks like Java... am I correct?

Comment: yes but theere is no difference in which language it is

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use recursion. For each depth you go, you add another character to the word.

Comment: Those loops do nothing at present, just create a local variable - is it actually doing anything inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tejs suggests, you'll want to use recursion.  You can't write loops to have dynamic depth, but you can recurse to any level you want (at least until you run out of stack space):

```
//Pseudocode!
void generate(dictionary, string, depth)
{
    if(depth == 0)
    {
        dictionary.add(string);
    }
    else
    {
        for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
        {
            generate(dictionary, string + c, depth - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Just start if off like:

```
dictionary = new Dictionary;
generate(dictionary, '', depth);
```

and you're off.  If you want to include all strings *up to* the desired length, it's an easy tweak - just always add the string to the dictionary, but only recurse if the current depth is greater than zero.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If your string was a number, you could get all the possible values simply by adding one until the number overflowed.

You can use this same approach for the strings; just consider each character a digit; add one the the rightmost character; if it wraps, increment the next character, etc.

```
// for strings of size N
char *str = malloc(N+1);
// init
str[N] = 0;
for (i=0, i<N, i++) str[i]='a';

int done = 0;
while (!done)
{
    for(i=N-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        str[i] += 1;
        if (str[i] == 'z'+1) 
        {
            if (N==0) done = 1;
            str[i] = 'a';
        }
        else break;
    }
    // do something with str
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note this method below is fairly inefficient. It could be made more efficient by using a secondary method that used stringbuilders, and then completed the strings in the primary method when you're done.

In any event, recursion is the best way to handle this.

```
List<String> generate(int len) {
    if(len == 1) {
        List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
        // notice I'm putting a char here, not an int
        for(char a=97;a<=122;a++) strings.add(String.valueOf(a));
        return strings;
    }
    List<String> shortStrings = generate(len - 1);
    List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(String shortString : shortStrings)
        for(char a=97;a<=122;a++) strings.add(shortString + A);
    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not totally wrong, What you are trying to do is to generate all possible strings of length `<=N`.

The simplest way to go about it is to map this to the way in which numbers are generated, i.e. by adding 1 to a number to get the next number. So basically start with `"a"` then add 1 to it to get `"b"` and so on till `"z"`. Now adding 1 to this will cause a carry over, so generate `"aa"` and then `"ba"` so on until `"za"` from where it becomes `"ab"`.

You can immensely simplify this if you can map a natural number to the string. To get the string just do this:

```
string getString(int val) {
    string str = "";
    while (val>=0) {
        int rem = val%26; // as there are 26 characters in english
        str = str + charToString('a'+rem);
        val /= 26;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Now just call this function to get strings:

```
void listStrings(int N) {
    int max = 26^N-1;
    string str;
    for(int i=1; i<=max; ++i) {
        str = getString(i);
        doSomething(str); // maybe print it or store in file
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.